# Asp.net mvc3 Hash(#) handing in routing system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, hash, routes

I use location.hash javascript mathod a lot at my ajax requests. Generally I replace standard
{action}/{id} with {action}#{id}

How can I introduce this strategy at rounting system?
I wol like write:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(text, action, controller, new { id }, new { })
```

and this generates /controller/action#id ?

Oh may be it's not good idea? 
How do you process ajax requests(open some entity at list?)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you seek is here:

[How to access AJAX hash values in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813800/how-to-access-ajax-hash-values-in-asp-net-mvc)

TL;DR - Its impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Remember: Routing isn't just for generating links; [it's also for parsing incoming URIs](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/03/18/38085/). Incoming URIs don't have hash/fragments on them, so the route you propose, if it were possible, wouldn't work for incoming requests.

You can write your own HTML helper, in lieu of `Html.ActionLink` to create the URI with the hash, if you want, but it can't be a route.

Answer (score 0):

this should work as you want.

```
RedirectResult(Url.Action("{action}") + "#{id}");
```